# Increment temperory variable value in case statement query

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Tring to calculate count according to coloumn value with case statement and I used following code for doing this:

```
SET @tempVariable1 := 0;
SET @tempVariable2 := 0;
SELECT EMPLOYEEID,count(ADNUMBER),
                        CASE
                            WHEN AEERROR <> '--' then @tempVariable1:=@tempVariable1+1
                        ELSE 0
                        END AS Ext_err,
                        CASE
                            WHEN INTERNALERRORS <> '--' then @tempVariable2:=@tempVariable2+1
                        ELSE 0
                        END AS Int_err
FROM employee_productivity_details group by(EMPLOYEEID) LIMIT 2,20;
```

It works correct when I run on workbench but when I set this query in PHP variable like `$sql` then it shows error. So how can I set temperory variable with in query? Any other way to do this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error. - its in yii framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, count(ADNUMBER),
       SUM(AEERROR <> '--') AS Ext_err,
       SUM(INTERNALERRORS <> '--' ) AS Int_err
FROM employee_productivity_details
group by(EMPLOYEEID)
LIMIT 2, 20;
```

Comment: No. I want to increment value by 1 according to condition which written in case

Comment: @anaghaaffinity . . . If this does what you want, then you should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me as per need.

```
 SELECT EMPLOYEEID,
     count(ADNUMBER),
     COALESCE(SUM(CASE INTERNALERRORS WHEN INTERNALERRORS <> '--' 
     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 0) as IntErr,
     COALESCE(SUM(CASE AEERROR WHEN AEERROR <> '--' 
     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 0) AS ExtErr 
   FROM employee_productivity_details 
   group by(EMPLOYEEID) order by EMPLOYEEID LIMIT 2,20;
```